# How to get rid of overlap when transforming background and having position fixed?

Tags: html, css, transform

I have a problem, as situated in the image:
[image]

When I am scrolling down, the background image I have (the blue one) gets a white area, while that should be blue too. The blue background should be blue everywhere, yet because it's *skewed* and I am using it as a fixed background image, it does not work, somehow.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <p>Here comes some text and so on</p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrapper {
   background: url("myimage.png");
   background-attachment: fixed;
   transform: skewY(3deg);
   min-height: 500px;
}
```

The white background you can see, is the body background. It should not be there, yet it is, somehow. When I would remove `background-attachment: fixed`, it works, yet I want to have it fixed as I am using parallax scrolling.

So it looks like `transform: skewY(3deg);` and `background-attachment: fixed` are blocking each other. I tried adding *z-index* and so on, but nothing is working for me at the moment.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: If you put together a working code snippet, we might be able to suggest a fix

Comment: This is the closest I can get: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QgdXPw

Comment: Are you talking about the red sloped strip one see half way down scrolling?

Comment: Nope. I can't seem to reproduce it here. It looks like it's a padding issue. Very very strange. Very frustrating. Is there a better way to do skew?

Comment: Well, if you can't reproduce it we have difficulties to help

Comment: No, skew is skew ... create a colored slope, yes ... with background, SVG ... if we are going to be able to help, you need to explain what you look for as precise as possible, maybe with some drawings.

Comment: I am trying to get rid of the crazy overlap, that's all. Beside that, it's just a skew on the bottom of every section with a background image.

Comment: Posted an answer. Let me know if that helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix so that slope only occur at the bottom, use a pseudo.

For the `skewY()` to transform upwards, use `transform-origin: right top;`, then set `overflow: hidden` to the wrapper to clip the upper part and the slope is only visible at the bottom.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  background: red;
}
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 1500px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.wrapper.nr2::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: url("http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/6790904-free-background-wallpaper.jpg");
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  transform: skewY(3deg);
  transform-origin: right top;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.wrapper::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: url("http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/6790904-free-background-wallpaper.jpg");
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  transform: skewY(3deg);
  transform-origin: right top;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.wrapper div {
  position: relative;
  color: red;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper nr2">
    <div>Some text</div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div>Some more text</div>
</div>
```